# Bones Wont deform with Mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, parent, auto-rig-pro

I just started using Blender and I wanted to recreate a viral creepy pasta. I have seen many tutorials and they all say for the armature to parent the mesh with automatic weights but nothing happens.

[image]

I cant seem to solve the problem, the bones move but the mesh wont move along with it

[Project File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hnmHuVoRSbegopSgWafiDw92Eshx1Hff)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

It looks the automatic weighting failed when you tried to parent the mesh to the rig. This is unfortunately a common occurrence in Blender. It seems to happen when you use somewhat dense meshes like you have.

There is a really easy fix though. Select both the mesh and the rig and scale them up a lot. I tested your file and it worked when I scaled them up 100 times. All this does is space things out a bit (a lot) more and the automatic weighting seems to like that better. Then apply the scale on both objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then parent, scale down (by .01 instead of 100 this time) and apply the scale again.

Comment: Thank You it worked!